# how can i interchange tokens between route in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I have this two routes I want to get token from response a in b how can I go about it

```
router. Post('/search', async (req, res) => {
  const tokenId = response.data.TokenId;
});
```

```
router. Post('/fare', (req, res) => {});
```

like getting the token from search in fare is there a way to do it in NodeJS?

Comment: Is this a session or are you chaining these two posts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it's best you store your tokens in the front end before sending to the backend ,you can store in your local storage